# Object in parameter specification

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-spirit

Why this sentence is valid in C++?

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), skipper<Iterator> > name;
```

Extracted from here:

- [Boost::spirit::qi - mini C compiler tutorial - function.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/mini_c/function.hpp)

The definition of rule is (resumed) the following:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename T1, typename T2,
                             typename T3, typename T4>
struct rule : boost::proto::extends<bla, bla>, parser<bla, bla>
{
  bla, bla
};
```

Extracted from here:

- [rule.hpp file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp)

The rule definition expects a type, however I send it an object. It is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, `std::string()` means the type of something that returns an `std::string` and has no parameters. For example,

```
std::string foo() { return "Foo!\n"; }
```

or an instance of

```
struct Foo
{
  std::string operator()() const { return "Foo!\n"; }
};
```

Comment: It may be interesting to note that one reason why this is unambiguous is due to the fact that template arguments can only be (a) types or (b) compiletime constant integral expressions. Since a constructor cannot be `constexpr` it is clear to the compiler that you aren't constructing an object but declaring a function type. The C++ FQA has a nice paragraph on that http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ctors.html#fqa-10.2

Comment: @sehe my understanding was that constructors **can** be `constexpr`, but since `std::string` is not an integral type, `std::string()` cannot be a non-type integral expression anyway.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty nifty! http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr. Thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 3):

You don't give it an object. `std::string()` is the type of a function that takes no arguments and returns an `std::string`.