# boost spirit std::vector<unsigned> parsed but not captured

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I am trying to parse and capture this string `"{ABC,HIJ}:{10,15,20}"` into `struct indicator_rec`.

The parse is successful, however, only the first set `{ABC,HIJ}` is captured into the `std::vector<std::string>` field.

The second part, `{10,15,20}` is parsed correctly, but fails to make it into the second field `std::vector<unsigned>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Output:

```
<equation>
  <try>{ABC,HIJ}:{10,15,20}</try>
  <indicator>
    <try>{ABC,HIJ}:{10,15,20}</try>
    <fail/>
  </indicator>
  <indicators>
    <try>{ABC,HIJ}:{10,15,20}</try>
    <indicator>
      <try>ABC,HIJ}:{10,15,20}</try>
      <success>,HIJ}:{10,15,20}</success>
      <attributes>[[A, B, C]]</attributes>
    </indicator>
    <indicator>
      <try>HIJ}:{10,15,20}</try>
      <success>}:{10,15,20}</success>
      <attributes>[[H, I, J]]</attributes>
    </indicator>
    <success>:{10,15,20}</success>
    <attributes>[[[A, B, C], [H, I, J]]]</attributes>
  </indicators>
  <parameters>
    <try>{10,15,20}</try>
    <parameter>
      <try>10,15,20}</try>
      <success>,15,20}</success>
      <attributes>[]</attributes>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <try>15,20}</try>
      <success>,20}</success>
      <attributes>[]</attributes>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <try>20}</try>
      <success>}</success>
      <attributes>[]</attributes>
    </parameter>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[]]</attributes>
  </parameters>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[[A, B, C], [H, I, J]], []]]</attributes>
</equation>
```

Code:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_symbols.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>   // std::regex not fully implemented in stdc++ yet

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace client
{
    namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii   = boost::spirit::ascii;
  namespace spirit  = boost::spirit;
    namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    struct indicator_rec
    {
    public:
        indicator_rec() { }

        std::vector<std::string>  m_indicators;
        std::vector<unsigned>     m_parameters;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    client::indicator_rec,
    (std::vector<std::string>,  m_indicators)
    (std::vector<unsigned>,     m_parameters)
)

namespace client
{
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    template <typename Iterator>
    struct system_parser : 
        qi::grammar<Iterator, ascii::space_type, indicator_rec()>
    {
            system_parser() : 
                system_parser::base_type(equation)
            {
                    using qi::double_;
                    using qi::_val;
                    using qi::_1;
                    using boost::spirit::ascii::string;

                    equation %=
                            (indicator | indicators)                      
                            >> ':'
                            >> (parameters | parameter)
                            ;

                    indicator %= (string("ABC")|string("HIJ"))
                            ;

                    indicators %= '{' >> (indicator % ',') >> '}'
                            ;

                    parameter %= qi::uint_
                            ;

                    parameters %= '{' >> (parameter % ',') >> '}'
                            ;

                    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(equation);
                    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(parameter);
                    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(parameters);
                    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(indicator);
                    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(indicators);
            }

            qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type, indicator_rec()>
                equation;

            qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type, std::vector<std::string>()> 
                indicators;

            qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type, std::string()> 
                designator, indicator;

            qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type, unsigned> 
                parameter;

            qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type, std::vector<unsigned>()> 
                parameters;
    };

    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_system( Iterator first, Iterator last, client::indicator_rec& rec )
    {
        system_parser<Iterator> parser;
        bool r = qi::phrase_parse( first, last, parser, ascii::space, rec );
        if (first != last) // fail if we did not get a full match
            return false;
        return r;
    }

    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_universe(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::vector<std::string>& v)
    {
        bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,
                              //  Begin grammar -------------------------------------
                              (
                                                        (+(qi::alpha|qi::char_( "_" ))) >> ':' >> '{' >>
                                                            (+~qi::char_(",}")) % ','
                                                            >> '}'
                              )
                              ,
                              //  End grammar ---------------------------------------
                              ascii::space, v);

        if (first != last) // fail if we did not get a full match
            return false;
        return r;
    }
}

main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::string calculator( "{ABC,HIJ}:{10,15,20}" );
    client::indicator_rec rec;
    client::parse_system( calculator.begin(), calculator.end(), rec );
}
```

Comment: You should use `unsigned()` in your `parameter` rule.

Comment: @llonesmiz +1 holy smokes!  That was it!!!  If you could add that as an answer and explain what why I need a `unsigned()` there, I would greatly appreciate it (in fact, I'm not sure what unsigned() means in this context).  tyvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472591/object-in-parameter-specification) from yesterday it's about the same. The signature of every rule needs to use this function declarator syntax. The type before the parenthesis is the attribute "returned" from the rule (its synthesized attribute) and the types inside are the inherited attributes (you can find a simple example using them [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html)).

So if you are not using these inherited attributes, you must use `rule_attribute_type()` in your rule declaration. Ideally a failure to do so would result in a compiler error but, apparently due to the heterogeneous nature of the [rule's template parameters](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html), unfortunately it's not what happens.

Comment: The Spirit devs have been looking at making concept/template argument checking result in more specific error messsages. IIRC they couldn't make it happen without introducing breaking changes. (Search the [spirit-general] list for a discussion on diagnosing errors with invalid Skipper types). Perhaps Spirit V3 will incorporate the ideas they have developed in the mean time.